# What does "implies including" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions, vocabulary

I found it in many texts, but I can not get its meaning, and I could not find anything on Google.

**Sentence:**

> Sustainable human resources development *implies including* gender in
>   the development paradigm.

Comment: You need to say what you "think" the sentence means. Do you understand the verb "imply" (3rd person singular *implies*)? Do you understand what "gender" means? Did you copy this sentence EXACTLY, word for word? Please supply the link. This question is crying for some detail.

Comment: I really have no idea what the sentence means. I know what each word means individually though. I took the sentence from Reverso, but if you type "implies including" into google between quote marks, you will find many books using it.  (unfortunately,  I cannot copy them, they are PDF files)

Comment: Then "show" users you know what each word means. The question is doomed to be closed for lack of basic research. Forget about Googling "implies including", if you must Google, then google:  "imply + Verb + ing" Or "Imply + gerund"

Comment: What basic research is? If you cannot understand the meaning using the context, or a dictionary, then there is no other way to understand other than google or ask someone about it. Might sound easy for an advanced learner, but not as easy for an intermediate one.

Comment: Which verb do you not understand, *imply* or *include*?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what it means:

> Should you wish to develop sustainable human resources
>   it would certainly **imply**
>   that you should **include** the concept of gender in your program.

Pretty much.

Answer (score 4):

The sentence

> Sustainable human resources development implies including gender in
>   the development paradigm.

is verging on gibberish. Some writers string together a collection of buzz-words, but the meaning of the whole can be hard to decipher. The author used "development" twice in the sentence, which is poor phrasing.

I suggest this paraphrase:

> If we want to develop sustainable human resources, we must consider
>   gender in our strategy.

Comment: Or, rather, "If we want peace in the office, we've got to make sure that the men and women don't fight among themselves."

Comment: @Ricky I don't even like the word "sustainable" which is often thrown into the pot as a politically correct concept. There are many examples of this type of verbosity, which is sometimes used to sound knowledgeable and important and even to baffle the readers/listeners on purpose. Just look at "development paradigm" which I paraphrased as "stragegy".

Comment: Valid points, all.